Issue Upgrading Elasticsearch from 7.6.2 to 8.14.2: ClassNotFoundException in Docker
I am currently using Docker version 18.09.1-ol, build e32a1bd and attempting to upgrade Elasticsearch from version 7.6.2 to 8.14.2. However, I am encountering the following exception:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
This error repeats:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
Is this issue related to the version of Docker I'm using? Should I consider upgrading Docker, or could this problem be related to something else?

The issue which you are encountering is not directly related to the version of Docker which you are using at present.
The main reason to this problem that you are getting an error, "could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliTooLauncher", indicates a problem with the Elasticsearch installation, and that too mainly with the classpath or missing files. This means that Elasticssearch can't locate the required JAVA Class to launch, which might be caused by incomplete or corrupted installation files.
In order to get this fix you can ensure that Elasticsearch Installation is complete. Double-check the Docker image or installation for Elasticsearch version 8.14.2. In short go through the process Elasticsearch installation in detail once again.
Another thing you should try is that, to fix this issue ensure that to make sure the Java version in your Docker container that whether is compatible with Elasticsearch 8.14.2.
It is of one use to upgrade Docker to solve this specific issue because it is much more indicating missing or corrupted files within the Elasticsearch setup itself.

I have further checked using Docker version 20.10.9, build c2ea9bc on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.3 (Maipo) (CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:server), and I found that the previous Elasticsearch issue has been resolved.
